# ng-change does not trigger when the checkbox is already checked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Here is the background:the checkbox was checked when "isChecked == 1" while its initalization,however,it doesn't trigger the "ng-change" event in its first "click" action.

```
<td ng-repeat="isCheck in item.check track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isCheck" ng-checked="isCheck == 1" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-change="f(isCheck, item, vm.modules[$index])"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: oh,i forget it,its ok now

Comment: @冯奕轩  Please paste your ng-change function code

Comment: @Hurix, there is nothing in ng-change function, im still in debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this working code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.item = {};
    $scope.item.check = [1, 0, 1, 0];

    $scope.f = function(isCheck) {
        console.log(isCheck);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="isCheck in item.check track by $index">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isCheck" ng-checked="isCheck === 1" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-change="f(isCheck)"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-checked cannot work alongside ng-change if ng-model is changed programatically, check official docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange